# What is the field sales_order_item.description field used for?

Tags: magento2.3

Can anyone provide any information on what the "description" field in the sales_order_item table is used for?   I never see it populated with any data, and it's not listed in the docs that I can find.
https://docs.magento.com/mbi/data-analyst/data-warehouse-mgr/sales-flat-order-item-table.html

I need to add a field to store notes on individual order items, then I noticed this apparently un-used field.   Can anyone tell me what is supposed to be stored here?